# optimize migration of table from csv to pg with self join update

Tags: postgresql, csv, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-performance

I have a CSV of size 1.5GB containing around 11000000 records and I am populating that data to Postgres table

What I have tried so far is:

```
set local work_mem = '4000MB';

copy truck_dispatch_logs(
    old_id,ms_truck_id,issue_date, ms_site_id, ms_product_id, act_dispatch, schedule_time, draw, truck_no, adjusted_time, default_schedule_time, log_date_time,location
) 
FROM '/home/truckdispatchlog.csv' 
DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Query returned successfully: 11696539 rows affected, 01:40:3635 hours execution time.

```
CREATE INDEX truck_dispatch_logs_ms_truck_id ON truck_dispatch_logs(ms_truck_id);
CREATE INDEX truck_dispatch_logs_truck_id ON truck_dispatch_logs(truck_id);

UPDATE "truck_dispatch_logs" as td
SET new_truck_id = temp.id 
from trucks as temp
where td.ms_truck_id = temp.old_id;
```

This query is taking more than 3 days so I stopped it.

In `trucks` table there is an old_id of type integer and id of type UUID

**here is the structure of table:**

"truck_dispatch_logs"

```
"ms_truck_id";"integer"
"truck_id";"uuid"
"schedule_time";"timestamp without time zone"
--some more irrelevant columns
```

**"trucks"**

```
"id";"uuid"
"old_id";"integer"
--some more irrelevant columns
```

**What can I do to improve this whole process?**

Comment: Drop all indexes before the `UPDATE` and recreate them afterwards. Higher `work_mem` should also help (set without `LOCAL`).

Comment: Maybe the second query was waiting for a lock. Did you check that? The indexes you create will only improve the join between the two tables if one of them as **significantly** fewer rows then the other and the join condition can use an index to filter out those rows.

Comment: can you post the table? Is the alter table statement at the top of your question relevent? It sort of distracts

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am sure that indexes help in join for sure. so why to remove them?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't know anything about `lock` so don't know how to check

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Comment: @G.B What makes you so sure? What does the execution plan look like?

Comment: I have already tried without the indexes but it was taking more time than with indexes

Comment: [edit] your question and add the execution plans with and without indexes. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: some of the irrelevent columns maybe relevent but the real reason that I aked you to post your tables is that we can see what indexes you have etc.